# NameError When trying to import LightGBM

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nameerror, lightgbm

I am trying to import LightGBM on python using `import lightgbm as lgb`, and when I try to do this I was first getting this error ModuleNotFoundError import lightgbm as lgb

I then did `!pip install lightgbm`, which seemed to install the program, but then I recieved the below error. I am not quite sure what is going wrong here. I would appreciate any help in remedying this problem, and finding the best steps to achieve this. Thanks!

---

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
1 #Build the LightGBM model
2
----> 3 clf = lgb.LGBMClassifier()
4 clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

NameError: name 'lgb' is not defined

Comment: run `python -c "import lightgbm; print(lightgbm.__version__)"` and tell me the output.

Comment: File "<ipython-input-2-52584d653689>", line 1
    python -c "import lightgbm; print(lightgbm.__version__)
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: Also ran it without the "python - c" part and got :




import lightgbm; print(lightgbm.__version__)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-c4c8da3c7bcb> in <module>
----> 1 import lightgbm; print(lightgbm.__version__)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lightgbm'

Comment: which environment you are working on? It's not installed there. To check whether installed or not. Always check the package using pip freeze and grep  `pip freeze | grep lightbgm` on linux

Comment: I believe I am using conda, but do you knowhow I could check/install to that environment? I am very new at this as I'm sure you have already guessed! Also, I am using windows not linux

Comment: well you can list all you env by: ``conda info --envs`  the one with the asterik is your current env . look at this doc: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html. I will suggest you to instead of installing everything using conda. Make a new env and isntall all the packages there and work on that env only.

Comment: Do you have a preffered way of making a new env? i was jost going to use `py -m pip install --user virtualenv`

Comment: `conda create -n <env_name> python=<version>` to activate `conda activate <env_name>`

Comment: For some reason the kernel will not finish and just keeps running when I try to create a new environment. Have already tried restarting my computer multiple times. You may not know why this is, but that is what is holding me up at this point!

Comment: Post images here. Do it on command prompt why involving kernel for this thing. It will create this type of issue only. Do it on terminal.

Comment: Turns out the issue was because I was trying to run it on 32 bit python instead of 64 bit. I uninstalled and reinstalled the higher bit version. Thank you! I will do it in the command prompt for making new env